# Rendering error in fragment section which is causing app to crash when i run the detail part

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Facing rendering error in fragment section which is causing app to crash when I run the details part:

> Error: A  tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.
>       -  (Use @layout/fragment_recipe_detail, Use @layout/fragment_recipe_detail_content_ingredients_item, Pick Layout...)

**recipe_detail layout code**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_recipe_detail"
    android:name="com.robotemplates.cookbook.fragment.RecipeDetailFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This is the section containing error:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_recipe_detail"
```

Especially this line:

```
    android:name="com.robotemplates.cookbook.fragment.RecipeDetailFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
....
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

remove 
`android:name="com.robotemplates.cookbook.fragment.RecipeDetailFragment"`
from fragment tag and use 
`tools:context="com.robotemplates.cookbook.fragment.RecipeDetailFragment"` in frame layout tag.

Comment: it also shows this error+>> The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21 Copy stack to clipboard

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yup, but app still crashes when i open detail of any recipe

Comment: add the full error to the question and the java code of this xml file.